# JQuery throwing an error about missing a window with a document

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I open the page (a mini-game essentially) I am working on and try to open Firebug, the page freezes and the *Script* panel displays this thing:

```
/*! jQuery v2.2.0 | (c) jQuery Foundation | jquery.org/license */
!function(a,b){"object"==typeof module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=a.document?b(a,!0):function(a){if(!a.document)throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");return b(a)}:b(a)}("undefined"!=typeof window?window:this,function(a,b){var c=[],d=a.document,e=c.slice,f=c.concat,g=c.push,h=c.indexOf,i={},j=i.toString,k=i.hasOwnProperty,l={},m="2.2.0",n=function(a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)},o=/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g,p=/^-ms-/,q=/-([\da-z])/gi,r=function(a,b){return b.toUpperCase()};n.fn=n.prototype={jquery:m,constructor:n,selector:"",length:0,toArray:function(){return e.call(this)},get:function(a){return null!=a?0>a?this[a+this.length]:this[a]:e.call(this)},pushStack:function(a){var b=n.merge(this.constructor(),a);return b.prevObject=this,b.context=this.context,b},each:function(a){return n.each(this,a)},map:function(a){return this.pushStack(n.map(this,function(b,c)
```

It's only a part of it and I think it's related to the jQuery minified file. But what is this meaning? And what are the possibile reasons why this is creating a problem in the page I am working on?
Sorry if I ask here, it's probably a basic thing, but if I google this code I can't find much explanation about it.

My whole JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var game = {};

        //point contexts to the canvases
        game.backgroundContext = document.getElementById("backgroundCanvas").getContext("2d");
        game.playerContext = document.getElementById("playerCanvas").getContext("2d");
        //game.flashFX = document.getElementById("flash-effect").getContext("2d");

        //set global positioning and scale vars
        game.width = $("#backgroundCanvas").width();
        game.height = $("#backgroundCanvas").height();       
        game.centerX = game.width / 2;
        game.centerY = game.height / 2;

        //create images array and counters
        game.images = [];
        game.loadedImages = 0;
        game.requiredImages = 0;   

        //array holding background stars data....
        game.BGstars = [];
        game.starFrequency = 1;
        game.starAcceleration = 1;

        game.player = {
            x : game.centerX - 61,
            y : game.centerY * 3/2,
            yStart : game.centerY * 3/2,
            width : 112,
            height : 75,
            animte : false
        };

        game.inertialState = true;
        game.residualAcceleration;
        game.residualFrequency;

        //TODO: hook with database.....OR create randowords generator....
        game.textsArray = [];  

        game.currentText = "";    
        //game.wordComplete = false;
        //game.wordDisplayed = false;

        //function to get random int within a specified range
        function getRandomInt(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }

        //init function - starting point of the game interactivity
        function init(){

            addStars(500, game.starFrequency)

            //draws the player TODO: create function to draw all elements!!!! 
            game.playerContext.drawImage(game.images[0], game.player.x, game.player.y);

            selectAndDisplayText();

            loop();           
        }

        function detectTyping()
        {
            var typedNow = "";
            var letterIDX = 0;
            var tempTyped = "";

            $(document).on("keyup", function(){

                game.inertialState = true;
                game.residualAcceleration = game.starAcceleration;
                game.residualFrequency = game.starFrequency;

                if(tempTyped == game.currentText)
                    selectAndDisplayText();
            });                      

            $(document).on("keypress", function(event){
                typedNow = String.fromCharCode(event.which);

                if(game.currentText.charAt(letterIDX) == typedNow)
                {
                    game.inertialState = false;

                    $("#char" + letterIDX).css("color", "green");
                    $("#char" + letterIDX).animate({
                        marginRight: "1px"
                    }).animate({
                        marginRight: "0"
                    });

                    if(typedNow == " ")
                        $("#char" + letterIDX).text(" ");

                    tempTyped += typedNow;
                    letterIDX++;
                    starsThrusting(true);
                    //console.log(tempTyped);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(game.currentText.charAt(letterIDX) == " ")
                        $("#char" + letterIDX).text("_");

                    $("#char" + letterIDX).css("color", "red");
                    $("#char" + letterIDX).stop(true).animate({
                        fontSize: "1.2em",
                        margin: "1px"
                    }).animate({
                        fontSize: "1em",
                        margin: "0"
                    });

                    starsThrusting(false);
                }
            });   
        }

        function pullAndFormatText(filepath)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: filepath,
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(text){
                    game.textsArray = text.split("\n");
                    for(i in game.textsArray)
                    {
                        if(game.textsArray[i] == "")
                            game.textsArray.splice(i,1);
                    }                  
                    init();
                }
            });
        } 

        function selectAndDisplayText(){

            $(document).off();            

            game.currentText = game.textsArray[getRandomInt(0, game.textsArray.length - 1)];

            var htmlToFill = "";           
            for(var i=0; i<game.currentText.length; i++)
                htmlToFill += "<span id='char"+i+"'>"+game.currentText[i]+"</span>";

            $("#word-displayer").slideUp("250", function(){
                        $(this).html(htmlToFill);
            });

            $("#flash-effect").fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500);            
            $("#word-displayer").slideDown("250", detectTyping());  
        }

        function starsThrusting(upThrust)
        {
            if(upThrust)
            {
                game.starAcceleration = Math.min(20, game.starAcceleration + 1);
                game.starFrequency = Math.max(1, game.starAcceleration/4);
            }
            else
            {
                game.starAcceleration =  Math.max(1, game.starAcceleration - 1);
                game.starFrequency = Math.max(1, game.starAcceleration/4);
            }                    
        }

        function decelarateStars(time)
        {
            if (game.starAcceleration > 1)
            {
                game.starAcceleration -= game.residualAcceleration / (60 * time);
                game.starFrequency += game.residualFrequency / (time * 60 * 4);  
            }
            else
            {
                game.starAcceleration = 1;
                game.starFrequency = 1;
            }
        }

        function shipAnimation()
        {
            var beenOut = false;
            game.player.y -= 4;

            if(game.player.y < -100)
            {
                game.player.y = game.height + 100;
                beenOut = true;
            }
            if(game.player.y > game.player.yStart && beenOut)
            {
                game.player.y = game.player.yStart;
                beenOut = false;
                game.player.animate = false;
            }

            console.log(game.player.y + " " + beenOut);
        }

        //updates all the data regarding game objects
        function update(){

            addStars(game.starFrequency, 2);

            for(i in game.BGstars)
            {     
                game.BGstars[i].y += (game.BGstars[i].speed * game.starAcceleration);

                if(game.BGstars[i].y > game.height)
                    game.BGstars.splice(i,1);
            }

            if(game.inertialState)
                decelarateStars(2);

            if(game.player.animate)
                shipAnimation();

            $("#controlpanel").html(game.starAcceleration);               
        }

        //renders the changes to game objects occured in 'update'
        function render(){


            game.backgroundContext.fillStyle = "white";            
            game.backgroundContext.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height); //clears the screen on every interval

            //creates rects -stars- for every element in the BGstars array
            for(i in game.BGstars)
            {
                var individualStar = game.BGstars[i];
                game.backgroundContext.fillRect(individualStar.x, 
                                                individualStar.y, 
                                                individualStar.size,
                                                individualStar.size);
            }
        }

        //put num of elements in the BGstars array (/w properly randomized properties)....
        function addStars(num, type)
        {            
            var starH;
            var starS;
            var starSpeed;

            for(var i=0;i<num; i++)
            {
                if(type == 1)
                    starH = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.height);
                else if(type == 2)
                    starH = - 10;
                else if(type == 3)
                    starH = Math.floor((Math.random() * game.height) - game.height);

                if(Math.random() > .5)
                {
                    starS = Math.random() * getRandomInt(1,2);
                    starSpeed = .5;
                }
                else
                {
                    starS = Math.random() * getRandomInt(3,4); 
                    starSpeed = 1;
                }

                game.BGstars.push({
                    x: Math.floor(Math.random() * game.width),
                    y: starH,
                    size: starS,
                    speed: starSpeed
                });
            }           
        }

        //the core of the game engine powered by 'requestAnimFrame'
        function loop(){

            //calls itself (hence also render and update) once every given interval - see below
            requestAnimFrame(function(){
                loop();
            }); 

            update();
            render();
        }

        //initialize and keep count of how many images get successfully loaded....  
        function initImages(paths)
        {            
            game.requiredImages = paths.length;

            for(i in paths)
            {
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = paths[i];
                game.images[i] = img;

                game.images[i].onload = function(){
                    game.loadedImages++;
                };
            }           
        }

        //check how many images are loaded against the whole expect amount
        function checkImagesLoading()
        {
            if(game.loadedImages >= game.requiredImages)
                pullAndFormatText("SpaceType_paragraphs.txt"); //if all the imgs are there we can pull the text from the text file....
            else
            {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    checkImagesLoading(); //...if not check again... 
                }, 100);
            }            
        }

        //pass an array with the path to the game images
        initImages(["imgs/ship_001.png"]);

        //start checking the images loading status
        checkImagesLoading();        
    });
```

Comment: Maybe if you post the js code of the page you are trying to open we can help you!

Comment: I don't have any error returned regarding my code. It's just something to do with the Jquery library I think...

Comment: JQuery is throwing the error because of an issue in your code. Btw if you use the normal version instead of the minified one the errors will be more human readable

Comment: ok posted the code for you...

Comment: Unwrap the document ready function from the self executing function that is completely useless as stated in the comments in your (?) code. Check if you still get the error

Comment: error still showing up...

Comment: What about doing some Google research for the error shown? I guess you are not the only one to report it

Comment: While the question's title indicates there is a JavaScript error, the question rather says that the page freezes while using Firebug. So, is your problem related to the website or to Firebug? And what is the exact error message you get? Please update your question accordingly.